# spring integration clarification on poller and its messages

Tags: spring-integration

We are using cron expression based polling in jdbc and sftp inbound channel adapter and we need special kind of message being generated that says this is the last poll for the day so that we can take some action.

Is this something possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.2 will have a new [Conditional Poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) feature that would allow for such a thing.

4.2 won't be released until later this summer but there's a [milestone available that includes this feature](https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/28/spring-integration-4-2-milestone-1-is-available).

Comment: Perfect, as we are releasing our project this fall. Thank you very much